# 0RA-00907: SQL MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update Shop.id, using UPDATE with a query to Area, comparing the attributes area and location of both tables.
So, I have this update which gives me

> Error SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I don't know what's the problem, what am I missing ?

CODE :

```
UPDATE Shop
SET shop.idarea= (SELECT AREA.id FROM AREA order by TO_NUMBER(AREA.id)ASC);
```

[image: Table Area & Shop]

[image]

Update Shop.area with area.id

[image: CREATE Area]

Comment: This is not clear. If the `AREA` table has several distinct `id`, which such `id` are you trying to use for update? If you need the "least value" then select `min(id)` in the subquery, don't use `order by`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including; the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for an example of your data; an English description of the logic you are trying to use; your expected outcome after the `UPDATE` is run. It is difficult to advise you on what you should do when you have given an incorrect query and removed it from all the surrounding context and not told us why you want to use it; please give us all the surrounding information to help us to help you.

Comment: You have a `SHOP` table with four `NULL` values; what is the logic behind which `id` values from the `AREA` table should go into which rows of the `SHOP` table and why? Please [edit] your question with an English description of the reasoning as to how the values should be allocated.

Comment: Do you want it where `area.areanum = shop.area` and `area.location = shop.location`? If so, then your sample data does not match as `area cocodrilos` is `32` in one table and `39` in the other.

Comment: You are right guys, I might missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause is not syntactically valid in the subquery; you need to either:

- remove it; or
- if you are on Oracle 12 or later, could add `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`.

So to make the query syntactically valid:

```sql
UPDATE Shop
SET shop.idarea = ( SELECT AREA.id FROM AREA );
```

or:

```sql
UPDATE Shop
SET shop.idarea = ( SELECT AREA.id
                    FROM   AREA
                    ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(AREA.id) ASC
                    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY);
```

However, that does not mean that the query will work (as there may be other errors, such as `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`, if there is more than one row in the `Area` table) or may not do what you intend as you have not told us what you want the query to achieve or what data is in your tables.

---

### Update

From your images, you probably want something like:

```sql
UPDATE Shop s
SET idarea = ( SELECT a.id
               FROM   AREA a
               WHERE  a.location = s.location );
```

or

```sql
UPDATE Shop s
SET idarea = ( SELECT a.id
               FROM   AREA a
               WHERE  a.location = s.location AND a.areanum = s.area );
```

Comment: If I try the second option, it keeps saying error parenthesis.
And the first option it says: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Yes, I do
**UPDATE Shop
SET shop.idarea= (SELECT AREA.id FROM AREA order by TO_NUMBER(AREA.id) ASC);**

Comment: @Roman For the second option, what version of Oracle are you using? For the first, what are you trying to achieve; because you are probably using the wrong method and need to use a `WHERE` condition to filter the `SELECT` but you have not described what you logic is so we cannot advise you.

Comment: Oracle version: **Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production**
I'm trying to archive with **UPDATE** get all id from Area and copy it to shop.areaID.
It would be easier with INSERT INTO, but I can't uset it.

Comment: @Roman I did say that the second option would only work on Oracle 12 or later so it is no surprise that it does not work on Oracle 11g.

Comment: @MT0 with first option you gave me, it returns **ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row**

Comment: @Roman Does the `AREA` table have more than one row? If it does then of course it will return that error. As I commented on the question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67475831/edit) your question (don't post updates to your question into comments on an answer) and tell use what behaviour you are trying to achieve and why you think using `ORDER BY` would help you. We can't tell you how to solve it until we know what the problem is that you are trying to solve. Oh, and please don't shout.